# Bernstein Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: c++, algorithm

For my assignment I have to implement an algorithm for the Bernstein polynomial defined on the interval [0,1].

My experiment needs to include the following function: f(x) = |ax|, for sake of simplicity in my code I let a = 1. When implementing the algorithm I used this Matlab code from our book (first picture) and the way the professors defines in his notes (second picture):[matlab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgff6.jpg) [professors defines in his notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kFoT.jpg)

My output has all the same numbers, I think the problem is I am not sure what value `k` needs to be from the formula. Anyway here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int combinations(int n, int k);
int fact(int n);

// Bernstein polynomial single precision
float Bernstein(float x[], float f[], int k, int n);

// Bernstein polynomial double precision
//float Bernstein(double x[], double k, int n);
//-------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    int n,k;
    cout << "Enter the degree: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the k parameter: " << endl;
    cin >> k;
    float x[n];
    double x_0[n];
    // stepsize for interval [0,1]
    double h = (1.0 - 0)/10.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x[i] = 0 + i*h;
        x_0[i] = 0 + i*h;
    }

    // Compute the f(x_i) = y_i values single precision
    float f_0[n], f_1[n], f_2[n];
    float alpha = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        f_0[i] = fabs(alpha*x[i]);
        f_1[i] = fabs(alpha*x[i]) + x[i]/2 - pow(x[i],2);
        f_2[i] = 1/(1 + alpha*pow(x[i],2));
    }

     // Compute the f(x_i) = y_i values double precision
    double alpha1 = 1.0;
    double f0[n], f1[n], f2[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        f0[i] = fabs(alpha1*x_0[i]);
        f1[i] = fabs(alpha1*x_0[i]) + x_0[i]/2 - pow(x_0[i],2);
        f2[i] = 1/(1 + alpha1*pow(x_0[i],2));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << Bernstein(x,f_0,k,n) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------

float Bernstein(float x[], float f[], int k, int n){
    int C;
    float B;
    if(k == 0){
        C = 1;
    }else{
        C = combinations(n,k);
    }
    int t = n - k;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        B = C*pow(x[i],k)*pow((1 - x[i]),t)*f[i];
    }
    return B;
}

int combinations(int n, int k){
    return fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n - k));
}

int fact(int n){
    int result = 1;
    for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
        result = result*i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Question:

Why does my output have all the same numbers, and what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bernstein(f,n,t)` with a function handle `f` returns the nth-order Bernstein polynomial `symsum(nchoosek(n,k)*t^k*(1-t)^(n-k)*f(k/n),k,0,n)`, evaluated at the point `t`. This polynomial approximates the function `f` over the interval `[0,1]`.

Example:
`bernstein(g,n,t)` with a symbolic expression or function `g` returns the nth-order Bernstein polynomial, evaluated at the point `t`. This syntax regards `g` as a univariate function of the variable determined by `symvar(g,1)`.

If any argument is symbolic, bernstein converts all arguments except a function handle to symbolic, and converts a function handle's results to symbolic.

Answer (score 1):

I execute the program and how you say the output have the sames results. Did you make some changes at this program after your post? I am interesting on it, because i have a homework at home about bernstein polynomial.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question and should be a comment.  Since you do not have enough reputation to comment as of yet, please continue to participate by providing solid, thoughtful answers to questions to increase your reputation.